# Sharing files in FileManager or App target to a WidgetExtension target

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a json file stored in the FileManager of my app and I want to access and decode it for my widget. I use the following url for the file:

```swift
let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        
let jsonURL = documentDirectory
    .appendingPathComponent(filename)
    .appendingPathExtension("json")
```

where filename is "list".

However I don't think the target can access the file in my app's FileManager as I get the error `Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “list.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."`

There might be some extra details you can use from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67402994/12939143)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share files between your widget and your app, rather than using the typical `.documentDirectory`, you can use an "App Group" instead.

You'll need to add the "App Groups" entitlement (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups) and then you can access a shared container url (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl)

Your container URL will then be accessible by doing something like `FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "APP_GROUP_ID_HERE")` which will return a `URL?`

You can append components to that `URL` just as you were doing in your original code.

Additional reading: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/sharing-data-with-a-widget/

Comment: Just to be clear, as my app has been out for a couple months now, I would also need to transfer the app files onto this new path so that the app and the widget stay in sync. As in I will have to add some code to move the file from the documentDirectory to the shared container?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, you would

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as accepted with the green checkmark.